# Why does my React app layout and site appearance change when I deploy it through github pages but it looks normal when I run it locally?

Tags: html, reactjs, github, web-deployment, github-pages

I made a react-app that works and looks fine when I run it locally (http://localhost:3000/). I tried deploying it through GitHub Pages, and the layout was all messed up (extra spacing,

---

tag looks different, etc.)I tried uninstalling and reinstalling gh-pages however this yielded the same results and I didn't know what else to try because it seems like nobody has really experienced this before.This is my package.json file. I have the most updated version of gh-pages.

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://adheenachacko.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.19.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-mailto": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native": "^0.60.4",
    "react-protected-mailto": "^1.0.3",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-rounded-image": "^2.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.12",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.87",
    "react-splitter-layout": "^4.0.0",
    "react-strap": "^0.0.1",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.87.3",
    "vertical-timeline-component-for-react": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 && yarn install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^10.0.15"
  }
}
```

I expected my page to have normal

---

tags to divide the sections of my pages, and normal spacings with (
).However the output after I deploy it makes the

---

tag huge with different colors which messes up the look of the page, and the spaces are all much larger, making the whole layout messed up.

Comment: When you use the developer console in your browser and look at the styles applied to those elements, are they identical to your local?

Comment: No they are not. In the developer console, it automatically added extra CSS styles to those elements that I did not apply in my local. Do you know why this is the case/how I can fix it?

Comment: What is the origin of those styles? Are they inline styles or are they from a class? If they are classes, are those the classes you wrote and expect? Sometimes (rare) during compilation, you can run into class name collisions and styles will get applied across unexpected areas

Comment: @deenchac any solutions for this?